# How to make simple FTP connection and download/upload file for iPad

Tags: ipad, ios4, sftp

I am trying to make simple SFTP connection and would like to perform simple operations like download, upload, pause download. My searches so far on internet has not yielded good results. Can any one give me the links to start with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you're open to third-party libraries  or not, but I've used the FTP and SFTP components from Chilkat in a iPhone project with success:  http://www.chilkatsoft.com/.

Comment: thnx can u give further links to usage  of this library